# Is it bad practice to have multiple Unicorn App Servers with one Nginx reverse proxy server?

Tags: nginx, unicorn

I have a Linux box running Ubuntu 14.04 with about 50gb of memory.

I've got a 5 or 6 Ruby-on-Rails web applications, each with a Unicorn App server, all served by an Nginx reverse proxy server.

Each app is hosted in a sub-directory.
eg:

- www.webserver.com/app1
- www.webserver.com/app2

Each app gets maybe 50-100 requests per day. They are all little apps to facilitate business processes at my firm.

My Nginx config file looks something like this:

```
upstream app1 {
    #path to Unicorn SOCK file;
}

upstream app2 {
    #path to Unicorn SOCK file;
}

upstream app3 {
    #path to Unicorn SOCK file;
}

# ...several more apps

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    access_log #path;
    error_log #path;

    ssl_certificate #path;
    ssl_certificate_key #path;

    add_header X-UA-Compatible "IE=Edge,chrome=1";

    root /srv/apps/app1/public;

    location /app1 {
            proxy_pass http://app1;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_redirect off;
    }

    location /app2 {
            proxy_pass http://app2;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_redirect off;
    }

    location /app3 {
            proxy_pass http://app3;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_redirect off;
    }

     # ...several more apps

}
```

This setup has worked without issue for a year or so, but I have this nagging feeling I'm doing this all wrong....

Am I going to run into problems if I keep adding apps? Is there a better way to do this?

**Update:**

By "problems," I mean:

- static resource path collisions?
- memory issues? namely, using more than I need to accomplish same behavior?

And by "a better way to do this," I mean:

- other than sending requests to the relevant unicorn server by parsing out the name of the sub-directory in the URL
- **should I be using a single Nginx reverse proxy to serve multiple apps?**

Answer (score 0):

For the same configuration into differents apps, you can use include directive.

Example, create file named **/etc/nginx/global_proxy.conf** with this content :

```
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;
```

And in **nginx.conf** your section /appX :

```
location /appX {
        proxy_pass http://appX;
        include /etc/nginx/global_proxy.conf;
}
```

And to increase your security, i recommend you adding **dhparam**, and add this to SSL configuration :

```
# SSL :
# drop SSLv3 (POODLE vulnerability)
    ssl_protocols         TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
# Recommanded ciphers
    ssl_ciphers 'EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH';
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;
# Diffie–Hellman key exchange (D–H)
    ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/ssl/dhparam.pem;
# config to enable HSTS(HTTP Strict Transport Security)
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains";
# force timeouts if one of backend is died
    proxy_next_upstream error timeout invalid_header http_500 http_502 http_503 http_504;
```

To generate dhparam.pem file :

> openssl dhparam -out dhparam.pem 4096

Comment: thanks for tip on how to condense the file a bit by including the proxy config in a separate file. However, I just updated my question so it is a bit clearer...what I'm really looking for is whether or not the general practice of multiple apps with a single Nginx revers proxy is a good approach, and if not, why?